# Terraform Inappropriate value for attribute "subnets": element 0: string required

Tags: terraform

I am upgrading from tf 11 to tf 12. I've run into the issue where `terraform plan` produces the following error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

   4:   subnets         = ["${var.alb_subnets}"]

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnets": element 0: string required.
```

The code snippet for this error is:

```
resource aws_alb "alb" {
  name            = "ecs-${var.app_name}"
  internal        = "${var.internal}"
  subnets         = ["${var.alb_subnets}"]
  security_groups = ["${var.security_groups}"]
  count           = "${var.do_module}"
}
```

If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change    `subnets = ["${var.alb_subnets}"]` to  `subnets = var.alb_subnets`

Its a update in terraform v0.12

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#referring-to-list-variables

Answer (score 6):

The error message indicates that the argument `subnets` for the `aws_alb` resource expects elements of type `string` in its `list` type. The error indicates you provided a value for the argument that is not of type `list(string)`. Although the value or type for the variable `alb_subnets` is not provided in the question, it can be assumed it is either a `list` or `map` given the name of the variable is plural. Assuming it is a `list`, you are casting it as a `list(list(any))` when you specify it in your config as:

```
["${var.alb_subnets}"]
```

Deconstructing this, the `[]` specifies a `list`, and the variable is already a `list`. The elements of the variable are not provided in the question, but they can be assumed to be `any` without sacrificing accuracy.

Instead of specifying a nested `list` by wrapping the variable inside another `list` syntax with `[]`, you can remove the outer brackets and:

```
resource aws_alb "alb" {
  name            = "ecs-${var.app_name}"
  internal        = "${var.internal}"
  subnets         = var.alb_subnets
  security_groups = ["${var.security_groups}"]
  count           = "${var.do_module}"
}
```

will be a `list(any)` for the argument value. If your elements of `alb_subnets` are not strings, then you will have to fix that also to ensure the proper type of `list(string)` for the argument.